# Windows Server VM created from Snapshot fails to Boot on GCE

Tags: virtual-machines, rdp, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a new VM instance on Google Compute Engine - GCE from a snapshot which I created from a Windows Server 2012 VM Instance a couple of days ago, but I've never been able to RDP cause Windows might not be booting up properly.

I get the Serial Port Output as following:

> SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20181112_143635-google) Total RAM Size =
>   0x00000001e0000000 = 7680 MiB CPUs found: 2 Max CPUs supported: 2
>   found virtio-scsi at 0:3 virtio-scsi vendor='Google'
>   product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0 virtio-scsi
>   blksize=512 sectors=104857600 = 51200 MiB drive 0x000f2a70: PCHS=0/0/0
>   translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=104857600 Booting from Hard Disk
>   0... 2018/12/27 13:20:39 GCEWindowsAgent: GCE Agent Started (version 4.5.4@1) 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts: Starting startup scripts (version 4.2.1@1). 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts: No
>   startup scripts to run. 2018/12/27 13:21:10 GCEMetadataScripts:
>   Finished running startup scripts

When I read the serial port 2 I get the following:

> Computer is booting, SAC started and initialized. Use the "ch -?"
>   command for information about using channels. Use the "?" command for
>   general help. SAC> EVENT: The CMD command is now available. SAC>

So, the firewall rule for tcp:3389 connection is allowed and I created other VM from snapshot successful.

I followed the steps from [stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682765/windows-server-2012-vm-created-from-snapshot-fails-to-boot-on-gce) and the [Google Cloud troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-windows#connectems) but I still cannot access this VM.

Any other suggestions to fix Windows boot problems on GCE?

Answer (score 0):

The source VM instance of snapshot had a ip internal in windows. I reserved the ip internal from GCP console and i created a new VM instance from snapshot successfully.

Comment: so did you fix your issue ?